# Why is the output of an `each do` statement different when it is put in a view helper in RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**Description of Query**

I moved some logic used a lot in my Views to a View helper. Exact same logic, but instead of getting the same result, I get a hash return instead of parsed data.

**Language Versions**

```
/Gemfile
ruby '2.6.5' 
gem 'rails',        '~> 6.0.1'
```

**Code**

--> Controller

```
/app/controllers/blogs_controller.rb

def index
    @search = ""

    if params[:section]
        @posts = Post.in_section(params[:section]).where(status: "published").includes(member: [:profile]).reverse
    elsif params[:category]
        @posts = Post.categorized_as(params[:category]).where(status: "published").includes(member: [:profile]).reverse
    elsif params[:tag]
        @posts = Post.tagged_with(params[:tag]).where(status: "published").includes(member: [:profile]).reverse 
    else
        @posts = Post.where(status: "published").includes(member: [:profile]).reverse
    end

    @sections = Section.where(id: SectionBlogMap.all.select(:section_id)).select(:id, :name, :slug, :order).sort_by{|o| o[:order]}
    @categories = Category.where(id: CategoryMap.all.select(:category_id)).select(:id, :name, :slug).sort_by{|n| n[:name]}.to_a
    @tags = Tag.where(id: TagMap.all.select(:tag_id)).select(:id, :name, :slug).sort_by{|n| n[:name]}.to_a
end
```

--> Helper

```
/app/helpers/posts_helper.rb

def tag_links(tag_name, tag_slug)
  link_to tag_name, tag_path(tag_slug)
end

def tag_links2(tags)
    tags.each do |tag|
        link_to tag.name, tag_path(tag.slug)
    end
end
```

--> View

```
/app/views/blogs/index.html.erb

<h4>Tags</h4>
<p>
<% @tags.each do |tag| %>
  <%= link_to tag.name, tag_path(tag.slug) %> &nbsp; &nbsp;
<% end %>
<br/>
<%= tag_links2(@tags) %>
</p>
```

--> Result

```
**Tags**

Active     Blue     Red     Tag 10     Tag 6     Tag 7     Tag 8     Tag 9     Yellow 

[#<Tag id: 1, name: "Active", slug: "active">, #<Tag id: 3, name: "Blue", slug: "blue">, #<Tag id: 5, name: "Red", slug: "red">, #<Tag id: 10, name: "Tag 10", slug: "tag-10">, #<Tag id: 6, name: "Tag 6", slug: "tag-6">, #<Tag id: 7, name: "Tag 7", slug: "tag-7">, #<Tag id: 8, name: "Tag 8", slug: "tag-8">, #<Tag id: 9, name: "Tag 9", slug: "tag-9">, #<Tag id: 4, name: "Yellow", slug: "yellow">]
```

**Question**

Using the byebug gem I checked the code and variables being passed and nothing changes from the view to the helper. So, I am unsure why moving the `each do` logic to a helper causes this. As I am a self-taught Ruby developer, I am guessing there is an explaination that correlates with the view/helper relationship that I am just not familar. Can someone shed some light for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
def tag_links2(tags)
  tags.each do |tag|
    link_to tag.name, tag_path(tag.slug)
  end
end
```

...returns `tags`, not the result of the `link_to` method contained within the `do` block.

Instead, try perhaps:

```
def tag_links2(tags)
  tags.each_with_object("") do |tag, to_return|
    to_return << link_to(tag.name, tag_path(tag.slug))
  end.html_safe
end
```

You may not need that `html_safe` on there.

Comment: Or `tags.map { |t| link_to(t.name, tag_path(t.slug)) }.join.html_safe`.

Comment: @muistooshort - This sort of just changed my life, BTW. I can't tell you how many times I do the `each_with_object("") do` thing. Thank you!!!

Comment: Cheers. We all have our odd little habits.

Comment: Both answers worked. Though as @jvillian states, the solution provided by @muistooshort is more elegant. Plus, adding `(", ")` to the `join` will give the added benefit of putting a comma and space between each result. So, I used this in my code to get the desired result `tags.map { |t| link_to(t.name, tag_path(t.slug)) }.join(", ").html_safe`.  @muistooshort, if you submit an answer I will mark it as such. Thank you both for your time and help!

Comment: The most important point IMO is what `tags.each` returns so I'm happy to leave this as-is and you can accept this answer.

Comment: Christopher - out of curiosity, why would you want a comma and a space separating the links?

Comment: One thing to mind here is that when you call `tags.map { |t| link_to(t.name, tag_path(t.slug)) }.join.html_safe` you're marking the whole shebang as safe. But if `t.name` originates from the user it might not be safe at all. https://makandracards.com/makandra/2579-everything-you-know-about-html_safe-is-wrong

Comment: @jvillian, I want a comma and a space because I am using this to print off the tags associated with a post. And I would like each tag listed to be a link to a page that shows all posts with that specific tag. But, when listed on the post page, I would like them in a list format on a single line. So, separated by a comman and space. :-) Just specific design preference there.

Answer (score 1):

When you are running code in a loop in ERB each iteration outputs to the buffer:

```
<% @tags.each do |tag| %>
  <%= link_to tag.name, tag_path(tag.slug) %>
<% end %>
```

Its actually like running:

```
@tags.each do |tag|
  puts link_to tag.name, tag_path(tag.slug)
end
```

However this does not happen when you are in a helper. Rails provides [concat](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-concat) that can be used to output in helpers:

```
def tag_links2(tags)
  tags.each do |tag|
    concat link_to tag.name, tag_path(tag.slug)
    concat ' ,' unless tag == tags.last
  end
end
```