# How to properly call 'render' on a partial, within a helper method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to move some of my view logic into helper methods, but I'm running into a problem when it comes to rendering the partials.

When I use a `return` statement, it will display the partial appropriately, but as expected, the use of `return` also causes it to break out of the `.each do` loop and only render the 'first' instance of the partial.

Instead of using `return`, I've tried using a different syntax (see the two commented out lines just below each render instance) but they either don't render anything at all, or the resulting layout/formatting is off (odd spacing and gaps).

The only way I've managed to get the result I'm after is to directly embed the conditional login into .html.erb itself. But obviously this is not desirable!

Any ideas how I can get this to work properly?

**helper**

```
  def render_appropriate_flyout_images_for(tag)
    if tag.child_tags.present?
      tag.child_tags.map(&:images).flatten.uniq.each do |image|
        return render "tasks/bottom_panel_flyout_image", image: image
        # render "tasks/bottom_panel_flyout_image", image: image
        # render partial: "tasks/bottom_panel_flyout_image", locals: { image: image }
      end
    else
      tag.images.each do |image|
        return render "tasks/bottom_panel_flyout_image", image: image
        # render "tasks/bottom_panel_flyout_image", image: image
        # render partial: "tasks/bottom_panel_flyout_image", locals: { image: image }
      end
    end
  end
```

**Corresponding method call from the .html.erb file**

```
  <%= render_appropriate_flyout_images_for(tag) %>
```

**Embedded straight into the .html.erb file, this is the only one that displays properly**

```
  <% if tag.child_tags.present? %>
    <% tag.child_tags.map(&:images).flatten.uniq.each do |image| %>
      <%= render 'tasks/bottom_panel_flyout_image', image: image %>
    <% end %>
  <% else %>
    <% tag.images.each do |image| %>
      <%= render 'tasks/bottom_panel_flyout_image', image: image %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

---

**UPDATE 1:** Thanks to @jvillian, I'm a little closer to figuring this out!

Everything is now displaying properly except for one small hiccup. For some reason, `#` get added to the html output. Whenever there are multiple images diplayed, the `#` will repeat again...

Here's the code I'm currently using for the **HELPER** (NOTE the use of `concat` as well as `end.join.html_safe`):

```
  def render_appropriate_flyout_images_for(tag)
    if tag.child_tags.present?
      tag.child_tags.map(&:images).flatten.uniq.each do |image|
        # return render "tasks/bottom_panel_flyout_image", image: image
        # render "tasks/bottom_panel_flyout_image", image: image
        # render partial: "tasks/bottom_panel_flyout_image", locals: { image: image }

        concat render partial: "tasks/bottom_panel_flyout_image", locals: { image: image }
      end.join.html_safe
    else
      tag.images.each do |image|
        # return render "tasks/bottom_panel_flyout_image", image: image
        # render "tasks/bottom_panel_flyout_image", image: image
        # render partial: "tasks/bottom_panel_flyout_image", locals: { image: image }

        concat render partial: "tasks/bottom_panel_flyout_image", locals: { image: image }
      end.join.html_safe
    end
  end
```

This results in the following (**NOTE the "hanging" # just below the image**):

[image]

[image]

Any ideas on how to get rid of the `#` signs? I'm not sure what's causing them to be there...

**partial**

```
<%= image_tag image.file_url(:speck),
  data: {
    crop_rotation_degrees: image.crop_rotation_degrees,
    cropw: image.crop_w,
    croph: image.crop_h,
    cropx: image.crop_x,
    cropy: image.crop_y,
    highlight_src: image.file_url(:highlight),
    imageid: image.id,
    imagepath: image_path(image),
    large_src: image.file_url(:large),
    parentimageid: image.parent_image.id,
    src: image.file_url(:small)
  }
%>
```

---

**UPDATE 2** So it seems I was a bit too hasty in saying this was "fixed". Looking at it again today, the `data: {...}` portion of the partial is being rendered separately as plain text.

[image]

How can I make sure this is properly included within the output generated by `concat`?

---

**UPDATE 3** As @engineersmnky and @milgner pointed out, the resulting text is part of the image_tag itself. I suspect this is caused by the plugin I'm using to lazy load the images essentially "overwriting" the tag upon view. That's a separate issue though :) As far as topic of how to render a partial within a helper method, everyone has definitely helped provide the answers and insights.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the output of an \`each do\` statement different when it is put in a view helper in RoR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59223272/why-is-the-output-of-an-each-do-statement-different-when-it-is-put-in-a-view-h)

Comment: Very interesting link, @jvillian, I think you're onto something here. The partial I'm trying to use includes `<%= image_tag image.file_url(:small), data: { ... } %>`. I'll keep messing with it, still not quite sure how to use the "concat" method that the link references...

Comment: If you find `concat` confusing, you can use the `map` method or the `each_with_object` method also mentioned in that Q&A.

Comment: Thank you @jvillian ! So it seems I'm getting really close now, the only issue remaining is that there is a hanging `#` that is now displaying at the end. I updated the original post with this information. Would you mind taking a look? I appreciate your help :)

Comment: What does your partial look like?

Comment: Hello @engineersmnky! I added the partial code to the bottom of the original post

Comment: the issue is the `join.html_safe`. `tag.images.each` returns the `Array` of image objects so you are then trying to join and html_safe the inspection of this return. since you are using concat the `join.html_safe` should be completely unnecessary

Comment: Good catch, replacing with just a normal `end` fixed it. 

Thank you so much @engineersmnky and @jvillian! I'm happy to mark an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the [linked Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59223272/why-is-the-output-of-an-each-do-statement-different-when-it-is-put-in-a-view-h), you should be able to do:

```
def render_appropriate_flyout_images_for(tag)
  if tag.child_tags.present?
    tag.child_tags.map(&:images).flatten.uniq.each do |image|
      concat render partial: "tasks/bottom_panel_flyout_image", locals: { image: image }
    end
  else
    tag.images.each do |image|
      concat render partial: "tasks/bottom_panel_flyout_image", locals: { image: image }
    end
  end
end
```

To reduce repetition a bit, you also might try:

```
def render_appropriate_flyout_images_for(tag)
  images = tag.child_tags.present? ? tag.child_tags.map(&:images).flatten.uniq : tag.images
  images.each do |image|
    concat render partial: "tasks/bottom_panel_flyout_image", locals: { image: image }
  end
end
```

Comment: Your repetition part can be reduced further as `concat render partial: "tasks/bottom_panel_flyout_image", collection: images, as: :image` no need to iterate with each as collection will do it for you

Comment: Oh wow! I never knew about that, thank you for the tip @engineersmnky!

Comment: Hello @jvillian (and @engineersmnky)! Looking at it again this morning, I'm noticing now that the data: {...} attributes portion of the partial is being included as plain text rather than as "part" of the image_tag. I've added some details into the original post as UPDATE 2. Any ideas what may be causing this?

Comment: @Spectator6 no it is part of the img tag. As mentioned by @milgner below remove the `=` to keep the output of your helper from rendering

Comment: Thank you @engineersmnky, good catch! I suspect it has something to do with a plugin I'm using to lazy load the images. That helps me narrow down where to look. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You are both outputting the text from inside the loop (using `concat`) as well as returning a sanitized HTML string from your helper. The latter is not required.

As such your code could look something like this:

```
  <% render_appropriate_flyout_images_for(tag) %>
```

Note the missing `=`: the output of the method doesn't need to be rendered.
This also means that you can omit the `.join.html_safe` inside the helper.

Comment: Are you *sure* the `=` isn't required? That surprises me. But, I am often surprised.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any Ruby at hand this very minuten. But from what I remember of `concat`, it immediately appends data to the output buffer. So I'm something about 99.9% sure ;)

Comment: Thank you @milgner! I hope you don't mind, but I'm giving jvillian the answer since he helped me in the comments previously. I wish I could mark both answers because both of you helped me understand what's going on :)

Comment: Sure thing! Glad to have been able to help out!

Comment: Hello @milgner! Looking at it this morning, I'm noticing now that the `data: {...}` attributes portion of the partial is being included as plain text rather than as "part" of the image_tag. I've added some details into the original post as UPDATE 2. Any ideas what may be causing this?

Comment: If you look closely at the output, you'll notice that it's not the data attributes being written there but the string representation of an `Image` object. There must be some place in your code where you're outputting this object, inadvertently calling `#to_s` on it.

Comment: Ah, good catch! That helps me narrow it down, likely something to do with the plugin I'm using to lazy load the images. Thank you @milgner!